# Default array value for a migration

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I am trying to set a new field to my entity which is an array of booleans. I defined it like this:

```
/**
 * @var bool[] $groupe_jours Selected days for the groups
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
protected $groupe_jours;
```

I added the initialization in the constructor:

```
  /** @ignore */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->groupe_jours = array();
}
```

Now I want to make the migration

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

This updates correctly the database:

```
ALTER TABLE licensee ADD groupe_jours LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)'
```

However, when I try to reload my pages I get an error like this:

> Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array

This is because the array type requires a specific string when the array is empty, like: `'a:0:{}'`

What is the best way to make sure that the migration updates the column correctly ?

1. Can I specify a default value for the migration
2. Can I put a default value in the field definition, that the migration should use ?
3. Should I update the database by hand ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sort of found an answer, but I am quite sure that there are better ones.

In the migration file that was created, in function `public function up(Schema $schema)`, after:

```
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE licensee ADD groupe_jours LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Typ
```

I added:

```
    $this->addSql('UPDATE licensee SET groupe_jours = \'a:0:{}\'');
```

But I am quite sure that there are better solutions, as this one looks like a hack...

Comment: This is actually quite a proper solution. Keep in mind that migrations never meant to be fully automatic. You will also have to correct generated migrations from time to time if you're going to work on non-empty database to ensure proper up/down working.